# Why are C names shortened?

Tags: c, function, naming-conventions, conventions

Why there is a function called `strcat` and not a function called `stringConcatenation`, or `stringConcat` or `string_concat` or something like that? Why there is a `clrscr` function and not `clearScreen` or `clear_screen`?

Does it have something to do with source code size in past days, where every byte was worth gold on overly-sized floppy disks? Or is this fueled by programmers' inherent laziness? Is it a convention?

Comment: At best, all we can do is guess.  You'd have to ask the authors of the C standard library to get a definitive answer.

Comment: Any number of reasons: faster typing, faster reading, more code fits on one screen so you can see more code at once.

Comment: There are actually real reasons for this...

Comment: In some early implementations of C, only the first eight characters of an identifier name were significant. Moreover, some linkers only allowed for six significant characters.

Comment: The C language was developed in the 1970's. Short names were popular back then. Fashion and style has changed. And remember that development environments back then did not have code completion, so if the name was stringConcat, then you actually had to type stringConcat each time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is old code cryptically written (short variable names)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351716/why-is-old-code-cryptically-written-short-variable-names)

Comment: The "faster reading" argument is absurd.

Comment: Some people like to be able to read their code. Overly verbose names are not readable. Lines become >80 characters (which is not just a terminal limit but a human readability issue) and must be wrapped, leading to too little fitting on the screen. I can't stand the sorts of function and variable names Java and C++ programmer types tend to use...

Comment: The six significant-characters spec was to be found in FORTRAN (not sure if it originated there).

Comment: @R., that's a great point.  I'd be a lot happier if my novels were formatted in a way that truncated words so that I could fit the maximal number of words per page.  I feel like the publishing industry is in a state of historical stasis until The Revolution comes to pass.

Comment: I'd read more novels if people writing novels were better at only putting on paper the words they need rather than filling space just for the sake of filling space... :-)

Comment: @TomZych hands off the stove bro faster reading is definitely not the case 90% of the time

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is partly historical.

In very old C compilers, there was no guarantee that more than the first 8 characters of an identifier name would be used to determine uniqueness.  This meant that, originally, all identifiers had to be eight or fewer characters, so method names were all made short.

For details, see [Identifiers in the C Book](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter2/keywords_and_identifiers.html).

Comment: I was writing the same response when the question was closed. +1 for speedy typing. ;-) According to the same reference you linked, there was no limit on the length of identifiers, it's just that only the first 8 were considered. Using more than 8, then, was probably a bad idea at the time: `stringConcatenate` and `stringCollapse` would have been treated as the same name.

Comment: @Caleb: Exactly - though some of the very early compilers (one I used) actually did complain about longer identifiers.  It was worse than that even, though, as many platforms really only used the first six characters in certain scenarios, too... In general, it made for lots of short identifiers, which I believe just became a kind of standard practice...

Answer (score 4):

When C and its associated tools were first being developed, input devices were not nearly as easy to use as modern keyboards.  I've never actually used an [ASR-33 Teletype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASR-33_Teletype), but as I understand it typing `stringConcatenation` on such a beast was significantly more difficult than typing `strcat` (and without autocompletion, you would have had to type the entire name with no typos).  It took a substantial amount of pressure to activate each key.  Output was also painfully slow by modern standards.

This also explains why common Unix command names are so terse (`mv` and `cp` rather than `move` or `rename` and `copy`).

And it's probably also why old linkers only supported such short names.  Programmers would generally create short names in the first place, so there was little point in using scarce memory to allow for longer ones.

In addition to all this, there's a case to be made that shorter names are just as good as longer ones.  Names of library functions, whether `strcat` or `stringConcatenation` (or is it `stringConcatenate`? `String_Concatenate`? `stringCatenation`?) are essentially arbitrary.  Ease of typing isn't as important as it once was, but it's still a consideration.

Comment: So you're telling me [shmdt](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/shmdt.3p.html) is just as clear and readable as `shared_memory_detach` could have been if it were used instead?

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Not really, no. But I can imagine that `shmdt` might be clear enough to someone who's familiar with it. Certainly abbreviation can be taken to extremes, but longer names aren't always better. It would be easy enough to provide a wrapper interface with longer names like `stringConcatenation` on top of `strcat`. It's telling that, as far as I know, nobody has bothered to do so.